# compare two latex files with pdflatex.fmt format and not for .cls format

Tags: pdftex, format-files

I would like to compare `old.tex` with `new.tex` file. I have find `latexdiff` is good for two latex comparison. But it's supporting only `\documentclass{article}`. But i have `%&update-article.fmt` format. Any ideas?

```
%&update-article
\begin{document}
\title{Article Title Here}
\maketitle
 some text for compare two latex files;
 \end{document}
```

Comment: i would assume that the "update-article" document is one to be used with a dumped version of some patching of latex.  as such, you can't reasonably assume anything about how the update-article will compile.  if you can if you can find how your update-article format was built, we can probably provide hints for making your documents commensurate with each other, enough that latexdiff can compare them.

Comment: If you are on Unix, a regular `diff -u` should help getting an idea of where the files differ (LaTeX source is plain text, after all). I learned (for `troff`, but it is the same with LaTeX) to split at logical places in the  text, i.e., after puctuation, a phrase always on the same line, and so on. Makes reorganizing easier (mostly shuffle lines around) and comparing versions via `diff(1)` simple. As an added bonus, placing a largeish document under version control gives understandable differences/merge suggestions.

Comment: We can't hope to tackle this, at least as it stands.